# Linking with android os settings in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to link with `android os settings` page.

Going to `Phone Dail` with `Linking` is work.

```
Linking.openURL('tel: +959 XXXXXXXX');
```

Can I use `Linking` to link with `android os settings` page like `android location settings` page?

Comment: What do you mean by `android native settings`? Are you trying to navigate from one section of your app to another, or to someplace on the phone OS?

Comment: @damusnet likely he's trying to reach the os settings page, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Settings

Comment: @damusnet , I mean `android native settings` is `android os settings` page that  say like @DagobertRenouf . let me edit my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Linking.openURL` can only open correctly formatted urls. There are no standardized urls for the [android settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Settings). You would have to write some native code to do this, and then build a [React Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) to trigger it.

Here is some example Android code:

```java
public void openWifiSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't u think this should be in the react native core?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini RN should not have to deal with all platforms quirks. I rather wish that Android had standardized urls for all settings. Meanwhile, it is up to the community to build those options.

Comment: anybody wants to do this mini bridge?