# Open Intent android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS using React Native Liniking.openURL()

Tags: android, react-native

How to open an Android intent in react native using Linking.openURL(). For example how to open WIFI settings menu of Android.

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/38893684/233404

Answer (score 1):

can you use some like as

```
async function goToSettings(ios: string = 'WIFI', android: string = 'android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS') {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    // https://medium.com/@contact.jmeyers/complete-list-of-ios-url-schemes-for-apple-settings-always-updated-20871139d72f
    await Linking.openURL(`prefs:root=${ios}`);
  }
  // https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java
  await Linking.sendIntent(`android.settings.${android}`);
}
```