# React Native - Android - Process Intent

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to process an intent URL in my react native app to trigger a payment in the Square mobile app.

In the web browser, I can use a link such as:

```
intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.register.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=...;end
```

But, if I add this to the Linking.OpenURL I get a failed promise in the react native app.

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/38893684/2955679

Answer (score 0):

The example from the documentation uses "https://my.website.com/index.html". You should replace this with a valid callback URI from your site and make sure to register it on the Square developer portal under the "Register API" tab.

You will also need to replace the example com.squareup.register.CLIENT_ID Intent extra with your Square assigned application ID from the developer portal.

Comment: I have all of the valid options and it still isn't working. The intent URL fails the promise check, the same URL works fine in the Android web browser, just not with Linking.OpenURL