# Expo - How do I open system settings on android platform

Tags: android, react-native, expo

```
  const url = platform === 'ios' ? 'app-settings:' : 'some-android-system-setting-url'
  Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {
      console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
    } else {
      return Linking.openURL(url);
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

I am using Expo to develop a project. I called the function above, it is working on IOS, while, it seems does not support Android. I checked some questions, some people said I need to create native modules, but Expo also said, it only supports pure JS. Anyone can help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking with android os settings in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893684/linking-with-android-os-settings-in-react-native)

Comment: Also read the comments in that duplicate. It's probably not what you want to hear, but the answer is that it's just not possible to do in Expo at the moment. Your best bet if you absolutely need to stick with Expo and not write your own native module is to open up a feature request on the [Expo Canny](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests) and hope it gets enough votes to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelCheng

Answer (score -3):

You can open with

startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);

You can return by pressing back button on device.